# High school geometry problem: Reflect a vertex about opposite side.

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, reflection, geometric-transformation

Let $ABC$ be a triangle and $A'$ be the reflection of $A$ about $BC$. Let $M$ be the mid-point of $BC$ and $I$ be the point of intersection of $A'M$ with the circumcircle of triangle $ABC$ (See figure).

> To prove that: $\angle ABC=\angle MIB$.

[image]

I am not able to make any progress.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $AM$ cuts circle second time at $J$. Then by symmetry with respect to perpendicular bisector of $BC$, the line $AM$ goes to line $MA'$ and circle goes to it self (also $B$ to $C$ and vice versa, and $M$ to it self), so $I$ goes to $J$. Thus $$\angle ABC = \angle AJC = \angle MJC = \angle MIB$$

Comment: Very nice proof.

Comment: we are asked to prove angle ABC = angle MIB not angle MIC

Comment: also how do we know MA goes to MA' ?

Comment: @Lozenges What greedoid means is that under the transformation of the plane "reflection about the perpendicular bisector of BC", the *line* $MA$ transforms to $MA'$.

Comment: @caffeinemachine How do we know this? M is fixed , A goes to some point other than A'. MA' is symmetric of MA with respect to BC. How is it symmetric with respect to the perpendicular bisector of BC?

Comment: Every two nonparalell lines are simmetric with respect to two lines (angle bisector) which are perpendicular to each other. In particular, since AM and MA' are symetric to BC so they are also to perpendicular bisector of segment BC @Lozenges

Comment: @greedoid Thank you